# Which is the most efficient way (performance) to add functionality to MediaWiki?

Tags: performance, mediawiki, css, extension, templates

I know of three ways to enhance MediaWiki functionality:

1. Using [extensions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Extensions).
2. Using templates.
3. Changing MediaWiki:Common.css & MediaWiki:Common.js

My question is, when I can choose which to do, which is best for *performance*? Obviously, templates only affect the pages on which they are included, but are they then faster than .css & .js changes? And which will slow down MediaWiki most - .css / .js changes or new extensions?

Specific example (following jscott's comment). A user wants to hide the numbers in the table of contents:

1. I can use an extension: [PSINoTocNum](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PSINoTocNum)
2. I can use a template (including this code: `.tocnumber { display: none !important; }` which I can include only on the required pages).
3. I can change [MediaWiki:Common.css](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/wiki/mediawiki/150715).

Which has most / least performance hit?

Note - this is just an example. I want to know *generally* which approach is best and why.

Comment: FWIW, the PSINoTocNum extension *requires* you to edit the `common.css` in addition to installing an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question won't have a proper answer because rendering changes (css, js) depend upon the visitor's computing power and connection speed whereas MediaWiki extensions primarily depend upon the server's computing power.

Comment: actually, I don't know about that - your answer is *very* helpful thanks. (Seems obvious now you mention it!)

Comment: Glad to help! In principle it's best to waste other peoples' resources (like your `display:none` example) versus wasting your own - but I see you already knew that!